# Expresso Store v2: Cart ID the same as Transaction ID

Tags: expresso-store

How can I make the transactionID equal the orderID?

My client would like them to be the same to make it easier for them to match up.

For some reason on this latest install of Store v2.0.6 running on EE v2.7.2 the numbers are out of sinc by around 20.

The latest order came though as #62 but the transaction ID for it was #42.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to make them the same from now on?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? In Store 2, there is no such thing as a "cart id", carts are simply orders which have not yet been completed.

Comment: Hi Adrian, there is a cart ID on the transaction email sent from WorldPay for a successful transaction which must be sent over from the checkout page? Previously that ID has tied up with the order no so both are the same. However now they are different.

Comment: Oh, that is the `transaction_id` (one order may have multiple transactions). It should match the transaction/payment listed in the CP order details page right? It's not possible to change that, but you should be able to see a text description in Worldpay with the order ID I believe.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes I should have said transaction ID. In the CP looking at the order details for order #62 the transaction ID is #42 and it's only a single transaction so I'm not sure what's going wrong here? The transaction ID comes through on the WorldPay email receipt which is confusing the client as it's different to the order #.

Comment: Can you email support@exp-resso.com to follow up on this? I believe you should be able to see the order # in the worldpay "description" field, but I don't have access to a worldpay account to verify this.

Answer (score 2):

After some great support from the guys at Exp-resso I now know what's happening here.

**From Exp-resso:**

*"What's happening is that in Store v2 a 'cart' can take up an order ID even if they are not complete. So if someone is on the site and has started adding items to their cart but not yet checked out then this will reserve an order ID as it is still an active session. This is actually a feature rather than a bug as it means that people can come back to the site within 24 hours and carry on where they left off with their cart which is good for goal conversion completed checkouts. Technically this was still the case in Store v1 but carts did not always take up an order ID so they would appear more sequential."*

There is no bug, but rather a new way of assigning cart ID's. Thanks Exp-resso for the quick replies/support.